# SQLite no such column when trying to read from database (android)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-asynctask

I'm having troubles reading from a db for my app, I'm fairly new to SQLite.

So I have a listview which is supposed to show a list of "expenses" coming from the database, When I do it with "desc" only it works just fine, but I tried adding code for a amount column and it wouldn't work.

I think the error is coming from the ExpenseDataSource class but I'll summarise the Main activity as well. It contains only the listview and you can add new and edit/delete items when you click them, if you leave a textfield blank the Edit becomes invalid. Every kind of help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

**Logs: **

```
04-27 11:55:33.877    1264-1264/cm3019.coursework1209323 D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb75deb70, tid 1264
04-27 11:55:33.927    1264-1264/cm3019.coursework1209323 W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-27 11:55:33.937    1264-1264/cm3019.coursework1209323 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-27 11:55:33.947    1264-1277/cm3019.coursework1209323 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: cm3019.coursework1209323, PID: 1264
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: amount (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, desc, amount FROM expenses
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
            at cm3019.coursework1209323.ExpenseDataSource.read(ExpenseDataSource.java:84)
            at cm3019.coursework1209323.SQLiteExpenseDataLoader.buildList(SQLiteExpenseDataLoader.java:32)
            at cm3019.coursework1209323.SQLiteExpenseDataLoader.buildList(SQLiteExpenseDataLoader.java:10)
            at cm3019.coursework1209323.AbstractDataLoader.loadInBackground(AbstractDataLoader.java:26)
            at cm3019.coursework1209323.AbstractDataLoader.loadInBackground(AbstractDataLoader.java:11)
            at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
            at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
            at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:57)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-27 11:55:34.067      389-499/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity cm3019.coursework1209323/.MainActivity
04-27 11:55:34.397      389-499/system_process I/WindowManager﹕ Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{b205d250 ActivityRecord{b205d0f0 u0 cm3019.coursework1209323/.MainActivity t5 f}} appWin=Window{b2007f18 u0 Starting cm3019.coursework1209323} drawState=3
04-27 11:55:34.397      389-499/system_process W/WindowManager﹕ Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (768x1280) to layer 21010
04-27 11:55:34.487      389-562/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing 983:com.android.mms/u0a9 (adj 15): empty for 2037s
04-27 11:55:34.527      389-400/system_process D/CountryDetector﹕ No listener is left
04-27 11:55:34.757      554-554/com.android.launcher W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-27 11:55:35.077    1264-1264/cm3019.coursework1209323 I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-27 12:00:34.537    1264-1277/cm3019.coursework1209323 I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1264 SIG: 9
04-27 12:00:34.627      389-400/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Process cm3019.coursework1209323 (pid 1264) has died.
04-27 12:02:01.707      389-428/system_process D/ConnectivityService﹕ Sampling interval elapsed, updating statistics ..
04-27 12:02:01.837      389-428/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1015K, 22% free 7327K/9304K, paused 87ms, total 94ms
04-27 12:02:01.877      389-428/system_process D/ConnectivityService﹕ Done.
04-27 12:02:01.877      389-428/system_process D/ConnectivityService﹕ Setting timer for 720seconds
04-27 12:02:52.597      540-540/com.android.phone D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 593K, 17% free 3430K/4088K, paused 50ms, total 51ms
```

**Here's the code for the data table:**

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by 1209323 on 14/04/2015.
 */
public class ExpenseDataSource extends DataSource<Expense> {


    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "expenses";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_DESC = "desc";
    public static final String COLUMN_AMOUNT = "amount";

    public static final String CREATE_COMMAND = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + COLUMN_DESC + " text not null, "
            + COLUMN_AMOUNT + "real not null"
            +");";

    public ExpenseDataSource(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        super(database);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean insert(Expense entity) {
        if (entity == null) {
            return false;
        }
        long result = mDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null,
                generateContentValuesFromObject(entity));
        return result != -1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(Expense entity) {
        if (entity == null) {
            return false;
        }
        int result = mDatabase.delete(TABLE_NAME,
                COLUMN_ID + " = " + entity.getId(), null);
        return result != 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean update(Expense entity) {
        if (entity == null) {
            return false;
        }
        int result = mDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME,
                generateContentValuesFromObject(entity), COLUMN_ID + " = "
                        + entity.getId(), null);
        return result != 0;
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Expense> read() {
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, getAllColumns(), null,
                null, null, null, null);
        ArrayList expenses = new ArrayList();
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                expenses.add(generateObjectFromCursor(cursor));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return expenses;
    }

    public String[] getAllColumns() {
        return new String[] { COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_DESC, COLUMN_AMOUNT};
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Expense> read(String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                                String groupBy, String having, String orderBy) {
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, getAllColumns(), selection,
                selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);
        ArrayList tasks = new ArrayList();
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                tasks.add(generateObjectFromCursor(cursor));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return tasks;
    }

    public Expense generateObjectFromCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Expense expense = new Expense();
        expense.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID)));
        expense.setDesc(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DESC)));
        expense.setAmount(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_AMOUNT)));
        return expense;
    }

    public ContentValues generateContentValuesFromObject(Expense entity) {
        if (entity == null) {
            return null;
        }
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_DESC, entity.getDesc());
        values.put(COLUMN_AMOUNT, entity.getAmount());
        return values;
    }
```

**DBHelper :**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by 1209323 on 14/04/2015.
 */
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "expenses.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(ExpenseDataSource.CREATE_COMMAND);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ExpenseDataSource.TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

**Main Activity where DB is used**

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<Expense>>
{


        private ArrayAdapter<Expense> mAdapter;
        private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
        private ExpenseDataSource mDataSource;
        private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;

        private static final int LOADER_ID = 1;
        // The callbacks through which we will interact with the LoaderManager.
        private LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<Expense>> mCallbacks;
        private LoaderManager mLoaderManager;

        private ListView mListView ; // the listview embedded in the main activity's screen layout
        // used to save the position in the list view of any task selected by the user
        private int mCurrentExpense;
        private DialogFragment mNewFragment, mDeleteEditFragment;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
            mDatabase = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            mDataSource = new ExpenseDataSource(mDatabase);
            mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            TextView emptyText = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
            mListView.setEmptyView(emptyText);

            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
                                        long id) {
                    mCurrentExpense = position;
                    Expense expense = mAdapter.getItem(mCurrentExpense);
                    showDeleteEditDialog(expense);
                }
            });

            // The Activity (which implements the LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
            // interface) is the callbacks object through which we will interact
            // with the LoaderManager. The LoaderManager uses this object to
            // instantiate the Loader and to notify the client when data is made
            // available/unavailable.
            mCallbacks = this;

            // Initialize the Loader with id '1' and callbacks 'mCallbacks'.
            // If the loader doesn't already exist, one is created. Otherwise,
            // the already created Loader is reused. In either case, the
            // LoaderManager will manage the Loader across the Activity/Fragment
            // lifecycle, will receive any new loads once they have completed,
            // and will report this new data back to the 'mCallbacks' object.
            mLoaderManager = getLoaderManager();
            mLoaderManager.initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, mCallbacks);
        }


        // Will be called via the onClick attribute of the buttons in main.xml
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.add:
                    showNewExpenseDialog();
                    break;
            }
        }

        void showDeleteEditDialog(Expense expense) {
            mDeleteEditFragment = DeleteEditExpenseDialogFragment.newInstance(
                    R.string.delete_edit_dialog_title, expense);
            mDeleteEditFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
        }

        public void doDeleteEditExpensePositiveClick() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            //ArrayAdapter<Task> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Task>) mListView.getAdapter();
            Expense expense = mAdapter.getItem(mCurrentExpense);
            Loader loader = mLoaderManager.getLoader(LOADER_ID);
            RadioButton deleteEditRadioButton = (RadioButton) mDeleteEditFragment.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.delete);
            if (deleteEditRadioButton.isChecked()) {
                ((SQLiteExpenseDataLoader)loader).delete(expense);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Delete confirmed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                EditText editDesc = (EditText) mDeleteEditFragment.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.editDesc);
                EditText editMaj = (EditText) mDeleteEditFragment.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.editMajVal);
                EditText editMin = (EditText) mDeleteEditFragment.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.editMinVal);
                String desc = editDesc.getText().toString();
                String majValString = editMaj.getText().toString();
                String minValString = editMin.getText().toString();
                if (!desc.equals("")
                        &&!minValString.equals("")
                        &&!majValString.equals("")
                        ){
                    Integer majVal = new Integer(majValString);
                    Integer minVal = new Integer(minValString);
                    expense.setDesc(desc);
                    if (majVal<=999 && minVal<=99){

                        System.out.println("TEST MAJ VAL " + majVal);
                        System.out.println("TEST MIN VAL " + minVal);
                        System.out.println("TEST amount " + (majVal + minVal/100));
                        expense.setAmount(majVal, minVal);
                        System.out.println("TEST amount2 " + expense.getAmount());
                        ((SQLiteExpenseDataLoader)loader).update(expense);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Edit confirmed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        System.out.println("TEST TEST TEST " + expense.toString());
                        System.out.println("TEST amount3 " + expense.getAmount());
                    }
                }
                else
                    doDeleteEditTaskNegativeClick();
                    System.out.println(expense.getAmount());
                    System.out.println(expense.toString());
            }
            // force loader to refresh the listview
            //Loader loader = mLoaderManager.getLoader(LOADER_ID);
            //loader.onContentChanged();
        }

        public void doDeleteEditTaskNegativeClick() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancelled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        void showNewExpenseDialog() {
            mNewFragment = NewExpenseDialogFragment.newInstance(
                    R.string.new_expense_dialog_title);
            mNewFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
        }

        public void doNewExpensePositiveClick() {
            EditText editDesc = (EditText) mNewFragment.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.editDesc);
            EditText editMajVal = (EditText) mNewFragment.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.editMajVal);
            EditText editMinVal = (EditText) mNewFragment.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.editMinVal);
            String desc = editDesc.getText().toString();
            String majValString = editMajVal.getText().toString();
            String minValString = editMinVal.getText().toString();
            Integer majValue, minValue;
            if (!desc.equals("")
                &&!minValString.equals("")
                &&!majValString.equals("")){
                     majValue = new Integer(majValString);
                     minValue = new Integer(minValString);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New task confirmed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                //ArrayAdapter<Task> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Task>) mListView.getAdapter();
                Loader loader = mLoaderManager.getLoader(LOADER_ID);
                ((SQLiteExpenseDataLoader)loader).insert(new Expense(desc, majValue, minValue));
                // force loader to refresh the listview
                //Loader loader = mLoaderManager.getLoader(LOADER_ID);
                //loader.onContentChanged();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New task cancelled",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        public void doNewExpenseNegativeClick() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New task cancelled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public Loader<ArrayList<Expense>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            SQLiteExpenseDataLoader loader = new SQLiteExpenseDataLoader(this, mDataSource, null, null, null, null, null);
            return loader;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<Expense>> loader, ArrayList<Expense> data) {
            mAdapter.clear();
                for (Expense expense : data) {
                    mAdapter.add(expense);
                }


        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ArrayList<Expense>> loader) {
            mAdapter.clear();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mDbHelper.close();
            mDatabase.close();
            mDataSource = null;
            mDbHelper = null;
            mDatabase = null;
        }
}
```

**And the loader**

```
import android.content.Context;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by 1209323 on 14/04/2015.
 */
public class SQLiteExpenseDataLoader extends AbstractDataLoader<ArrayList<Expense>>{

    private DataSource<Expense> mDataSource;
    private String mSelection;
    private String[] mSelectionArgs;
    private String mGroupBy;
    private String mHaving;
    private String mOrderBy;

    public SQLiteExpenseDataLoader(Context context, DataSource dataSource, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                                String groupBy, String having, String orderBy) {
        super(context);
        mDataSource = dataSource;
        mSelection = selection;
        mSelectionArgs = selectionArgs;
        mGroupBy = groupBy;
        mHaving = having;
        mOrderBy = orderBy;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Expense> buildList() {
        ArrayList<Expense> expenseList = mDataSource.read(mSelection, mSelectionArgs, mGroupBy, mHaving,
                mOrderBy);
        return expenseList;
    }

    public void insert(Expense entity) {
        new InsertExpense(this).execute(entity);
    }

    public void update(Expense entity) {
        new UpdateExpense(this).execute(entity);
    }

    public void delete(Expense entity) {
        new DeleteExpense(this).execute(entity);
    }

    private class InsertExpense extends ContentChangingExpense<Expense, Void, Void> {
        InsertExpense(SQLiteExpenseDataLoader loader) {
            super(loader);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Expense... params) {
            mDataSource.insert(params[0]);
            return (null);
        }
    }

    private class UpdateExpense extends ContentChangingExpense<Expense, Void, Void> {
        UpdateExpense(SQLiteExpenseDataLoader loader) {
            super(loader);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Expense... params) {
            mDataSource.update(params[0]);
            return (null);
        }
    }

    private class DeleteExpense extends ContentChangingExpense<Expense, Void, Void> {
        DeleteExpense(SQLiteExpenseDataLoader loader) {
            super(loader);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Expense... params) {
            mDataSource.delete(params[0]);
            return (null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you missed space between `COLUMN_AMOUNT`  and `real`.So change

```
 + COLUMN_AMOUNT + "real not null"
```

to

```
 + COLUMN_AMOUNT + " real not null"
```

And also don't forget to delete existing app from device before retry.

Comment: It was this, thanks :) I've only been doing this for a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing the database version by 1? If you make changes to the structure of the database, you need to do this

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall your app and run again with changes made below

```
public static final String CREATE_COMMAND = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + " ( "
            + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + COLUMN_DESC + " text not null, "
            + COLUMN_AMOUNT + " real not null"
            +");";
```